# sql query into hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am a beginner at hibernate and have read up a lot but I'm stuck at this one point.
In my JSF app that I'm implementing hibertate, I have this SQL query that works in my database:

```
SELECT *
FROM CourseProduct
INNER JOIN Course
ON CourseProduct.number=Course.number
inner join Product
on CourseProduct.product=Product.product;
```

I am trying to do the same thing with hibernate for my JSF application. So far I came up with:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Course.class)
     .setFetchMode("product", FetchMode.JOIN)
     .setFetchMode("number", FetchMode.JOIN)
     .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
     .list();
```

Is this correct or completely wrong? Also how do I access the fields from the results (if I even have to do that, since hibernate populates the classes for me)? It seems like the results I get are only the the Course Table, the value of the primary key in Product, but not the other 2 fields in the table Product.

EDIT

I guess I solved my own problem. It looks as though the above code is correct, I just didn't realize that in order to access the class Product I had to access it from the Set in the Course class! I just used an iterator to get the data I need in the get method for the set of Products in the Course class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved my own problem. It looks as though the above code is correct, I just didn't realize that in order to access the class Product I had to access it from the Set in the Course class! I just used an iterator to get the data I need in the get method for the set of Products in the Course class.

Update: I really solved the problem. I just got rid of hibernate. The sql query works fine, got my data using a perpared Statement and the result set using the regular old way (java.sql.DriverManager). 
For some reason the hibernate driver didn't even like using my statement as a native SQL (kept giving me an exception trying to convert an Integer). I googled the problem and they say it's a bug in hibernate!